# How to access data in Facebook graph request result response

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have Facebook login working and I am able to sign in, get details etc. But one thing that is stumping me is how to read the data from the result response from the graphapi calls.

```
Optional({
    data =     {
        height = 50;
        "is_silhouette" = 1;
        url = "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=108656723630605&height=50&width=50&ext=1554751119&hash=AeRq_Hgo5yU28P3f";
        width = 50;
    };
})
```

The above is my response and I want to access the url parameter.

My code (which is terrible, sorry in advance) is :

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: friendID, parameters: ["fields":"picture"])?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print("Error in getting friends picture")
    } else {
        let friendPicture = result as! [String:AnyObject]
        print(friendPicture["picture"])
        let nestedJSON = friendPicture["picture"] //as? [[String:String]]
        print("The below should be just URL// above is entire response")
    }
})
```

Comment: Why are you accessing `picture` on the dictionary since there's no such key there?

Comment: As ajeferson asks, why? Also, do you have an error message?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses! ajeferson, apparently there was, I was able to access that object, just not the ones inside it.

Magnas, I was getting empty strings when I tried to access anything inside it or something like "Subscript not allowed"

I finally spent some time and figured out how to see what the dictionary had and found the right one phew!